Section completed multiple times
I am a developer new to Google forms and have a form with multiple sections.  One section is collecting room information for a home. I would like the ability for the user to fill this section out for each room with a question at the end of the section "Do you have an additional room?". At that point a blank section is displayed. When the form is submitted, I would like it to be stored on the same Google sheet row.
I know that I can create duplicates for this section for the max number of rooms. But, I am hoping that there is a better solution as I could have upward of 20 rooms.
I have tried using the navigation feature, but when it returns me to the forms Room section it is the same the initial room response, not a blank section.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question doesn't seem to be about a specific problem unique to programming (ref. [tour]), so it's off-topic here.

Is this an XY problem where the focus is on a solution rather than the actual problem. The problem, as I see it, is there are 20+ rooms so a navigation dropdown would list 20+ rooms using the "Go to section on answer" feature. Each room has its own section containing as many questions as relevant PLUS a "Got another room" question. If the answer to the latter is "Yes" then the Form returns to the navigation dropdown, if "No" the Form can be submitted. Having built one section, the others can be duplicated; I don't know of an easier method.

Tedinoz, Thank you for your response.  I was wasn't sure if using a programming approach with scripting would be more appropriate, but as you mentioned in your solution it is easy to implement.  I will try your approach using the dropdown.
